# How to make your selenium script unbreakable?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a selenium script using Java to automate a website workflow. I want to run this script 24/7 and make sure that it's always running without any crashes. I want to make it unbreakable.

Now let's say that the script has been running fine for some hours and suddenly chrome crashes so how do I make my script launch the chrome and start the execution from the start? Do I need to use any framework? I am learning TestNG.

Comment: After some point or another your browser is going to crash and chrome being a memory hogger, there are more chances of it crashing. May I know why do you want to run your test suite 24x7, which is really a bad idea.

Comment: We are writing software that will keep on checking for files in a specific folder and once a file is available in that folder, we need to upload it on the website and do some further process. Is selenium the right approach? We are planning on shifting to ElectronJS.